# Plotly python rows

Tags: plotly, rows

I have code that looks like this. It works well, but I want to modify the size of columns:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.read_csv('nasdaq.csv')
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)  
fig.append_trace(
    go.Candlestick(
        x=df.index,
        open=df['Open'],
        high=df['High'],
        low=df['Low'],
        close=df['Close'],
    ), row=1, col=1  
)
fig.append_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df.index,
        y=df['S_slowK'],
        line=dict(color='#ff9900', width=2),
        name='Slow K',
    ), row=2, col=1  
)
fig.append_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df.index,
        y=df['RSI'],
        line=dict(color='blue', width=2),
        name='RSI',

    ), row=2, col=1  
)
fig.append_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df.index,
        y=df['S_FastD'],
        line=dict(color='#000000', width=2),
        name='Fast D'
    ), row=2, col=1  
)
fig.update_yaxes(range=[-10, 110], row=2, col=1)
fig.add_hline(y=0, col=1, row=2, line_color="#666", line_width=2)
fig.add_hline(y=100, col=1, row=2, line_color="#666", line_width=2)
fig.add_hline(y=50, col=1, row=2, line_color="red", line_width=2)
fig.add_hline(y=20, col=1, row=2, line_color='#336699', line_width=2, line_dash='dash')
fig.add_hline(y=80, col=1, row=2, line_color='#336699', line_width=2, line_dash='dash')
fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
fig.update_layout(
    width=1800,
    height=800,
    title_text= "nasdaq",
    yaxis_tickformat='M') 
fig.show()
```

However, he chart window and the indicators window have the same size. How can I make the chart bigger than indicators?

[image: output of my code]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Just add more arguments to the make subplots function like this:

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1,horizontal_spacing=0,row_heights=[15,2],vertical_spacing=0.01)
```

You can see row heights must be a list containing two numbers.